# Changing the initial path of the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation

I have been using the **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017** to compile C# console applications that I've been writing in Visual Studio Code for practice.  When I open it the default path is:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community>**

It's getting to be tediuos navigating to the folder where I'm storing my code files and I'd like to change the initial path to something like:

**C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\FOLDERNAME>**

- Is there a way to do this?
- If not is there a trick to quickly changing to a specified location?
- Are there better resources I could be using to compile my programs?

---

The only other place I've found this question is here:

[Change Default Visual Studio Command Prompt Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135480/change-default-visual-studio-command-prompt-location)

The shortcuts and the "vcvarsall.bat" files that the answers suggest to modify here don't appear in any of my Visual Studio folders.  Beyond that I don't really understand the answers and can't really tell if they are applicable to what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do as has been suggested by someone else is to edit the VsDevCmd.bat (you may want to actually make a copy of this file and leave the original intact) and before the final exit line you add:

```
cd <your-source-path>
```

I don't know of another solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat, and on the penultimate line (before exit /B 0) write

```
cd <path-you-wanted>
```

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a bundled file as per the other answers is generally not recommended as it could be overwritten with an upgrade or repair, however unlikely, or interfere with something else that relies on the standard behaviour.

The question linked by the asker actually does provide a nice solution that works apparently from VS 2017 forward, I tested in VS 2019 and worked correctly, it is simply setting the environment variable `VSCMD_START_DIR` to the desired starting folder, you can find here is the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46051460/276874).